# Asp.Net MVC 5 make a li to be first at ul

Tags: jquery

I am using signaIR in my chat system. I also save the messages to database. So what I am trying to do is If a user wants to continue a previous conversation and adds a new message, that messages comes to below of the page but when I get the previous messages I order descending by date and the newest messages comes to top of the page.

This messages comes from database.

```
<ul id="discussion">
           @foreach (var item in Model){
            <li>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Message)</li>
           }
</ul>
```

when I add messages by signaIR, I use this code. I want this `<li>` to be first at `<ul>`

```
 $('#discussion').append('<li>' + message' + </li>');
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/prepend/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**prepend()**](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) instead of `append()`:

```
 $('#discussion').prepend('<li>' + message' + </li>');
```

From [**Jquery DOCS**](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/):

> > The .prepend() method inserts the specified content as the first child of each element in the jQuery collection (To insert it as the last child, use .append()).